# DPAPI data protection scope

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I've been doing some research into Microsoft DPAPI and have a question that doesn't seem to be answered by the documentation.

I'm building a test web app that stores a user password using the [ProtectedData.Protect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fh8203k(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The documentation states that in most cases this data should be stored in the scope of the CurrentUser, as LocalMachine allows anyone in the same machine context to decrypt that information (in this case, user password).

**Question**: So, here is the thing: What user context is this related to, the machine user running the web server (IIS) or the user logged into the web application? (The web app uses Windows authentication, which is Active Directory in this case.) Which scope will provide the most secure scheme?

Comment: This is a really tech-specific question. You might get better results in the SE side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CurrentUser refers to the Windows user executing the process, not the Windows user via authentication, so that would be whoever is running the app pool. E.g. network service, system, specified user, etc.